# getting "the field name is required" after uploading the image

Tags: python, django

after uploading the image to a form when i submit the form it still shows "the field is required" error
in models.py:

```
 class Members(models.Model):
     image=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",default='')
```

in forms.py:

```
 class CreateOne(forms.Form):
     image=forms.ImageField(required=True)
```

in create.html:

```
  <form class="form-inline"  action="create" method="POST" 
         enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
```

in views.py:

```
 def create(request):
     member = Members(image=request.FILES['image'])
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = forms.CreateOne(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():            
            member.save()
         return redirect('/')
     else:
        form = CreateOne()
```

Comment: How did you invoke the form? With `request.FILES` as well? Can you share the view?

Comment: i have edited the code can u check it once

Comment: But where do you use the form in your `create` view?

Comment: added code according to requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand the way to use a `Form` the wrong way. The idea of such `Form` when you write `some_form.save()` it makes the changes (and for example create a model instance and save it to the database).

Since most forms (like probably this one) are related to a single model, Django has a `ModelForm`, which offers extra convenience:

```
class CreateOne(forms.ModelForm):
    image=forms.ImageField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Members
        fields = ['image']
```

Then we can make a view that will create an instance in case of a valid form with:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateOne(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CreateOne()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form}
```

You probably also do *not* want to redirect in case the `form` was *not* valid, since then you probably want to give the user feedback that the form was not valid (and show the corresponding errors).

Comment: Is there any way of using 'forms.Form' without using 'forms.ModelForm'???

Comment: @padmajacherukuri: of course, simply reimplement `BaseModelForm` yourself, it is a subclass of a `BaseForm`, so there is nothing magical about this.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: the two are not the same, since then you *redefine* the form, and thus lose the error information.

Comment: @padmajacherukuri: you can inspect the source code here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/models/. Of course you only will need to implement 30-80% of the magic in order to get it work.

Comment: seems missing some indentation, can you make it right?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: yes and that is now fixed, but the `else` codepath should still be included, since it "shields" against a non-valid POST request.

Comment: I think you forgot to handle the case where the form is **not valid**

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: no, since then we have an invalid form, and that form will be `render(..)`ed (and if the template is properly defined, with the errors displayed). See for example here a template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: It was unfortunately that what the refactoring would have destroyed beyond repair: by creating a new form, you basically completely erase the old one, and thus the errors could no longer get displayed.